# Java Swing: JOptionPane appears by itself without parent window when restored?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JOptionPane which appears on top of it's parent JFrame window, but when the application is minimized and restored, only the JOptionPane will show and not the parent JFrame.

How to fix this bug?

Comment: I think this is because *`JOptionPane` is `modal` dialog*.

Comment: i think you should check if JFrame is iconified or not. so before show joption pane, if jframe is iconified restore it and show joptionpane

Comment: I'm not sure how it is possible to minimize the JFrame while the JOptionPane is up.

Comment: everything gets minimized but upon restoration only the joptionpane comes up, if i close the joptionpane, then the parent window will display finally.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad : possible on windows machine when we press `WINDOW_KEY + D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOptionPane` is a modal dialog box.

It means first you need to handle/close this dialog box then you will be able to access your main window.

So when you minimize everything and then restore it, it firstly shows the JOptionPane when you will close it or what it is supposed to do ONLY then you will get the main window.

It's not a bug. It is just how modal things work.

You will not be able to even Minimize the main window from icon when JOptionPane is up. You can minimize everything like with `Window + D` key or `Window + M` key in Windows PCs.